# Strong equivalence between intrinsic and extrinsic metrics on $GL_n^+$?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, matrices, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

$\newcommand{\til}{\tilde}$

Lately, I have become interested in comparing intrinsic and extrinsic metrics on Riemannian manifolds.

Consider $GL_n^+$ (invertible matrices , $\det >0$) as an open Riemannian submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

We have two metrics on $GL_n^+$ (in the sense of metric spaces); intrinsic $d^{int}$ (when we only allow paths which stay inside $GL_n^+$) and extrinsic $d^{ext}$ (the standard Euclidean metric).

**Clarification:** $d^{int}$ is the Riemann distance function on $GL_n^+$ induced by the standard Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ (i.e I consider $GL_n^+$ as a Riemannian submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2})$

Of course $d^{ext} \le d^{int}$. For some matrices $d^{ext}(A,B) < d^{int}(A,B)$;

If $\gamma(t)=A+t(B-A)$, then $\det(\gamma(t))$ is a polynomial which can be negative on a subinterval of $[0,1]$. (i.e the minimizing geodesic in the Euclidean space, is contained in $GL^{-}$ for some time)

(see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1495902/104576) to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492269/computing-explicitly-the-riemannian-distance-on-gl-n) for details on this specific case, and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1500621/104576) for a cleaner proof that "nearly minimizing paths are nearly geodesic")

---

Note that $d^{ext},d^{int}$ both generate the same topology on $GL_n^+$.
Moreover, both are incomplete.

So, the following natural question arises:

**Are $d^{ext},d^{int}$ strongly equivalent? i.e; Is it true that**

$d^{int} \le C \cdot d^{ext} \text{ for some } C \in \mathbb{R}$?

---

Comment: +1 for stimulating a research paper (see below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In two dimensions the condition $ad-bc=0$ translates into $(a+d)^2-(a-d)^2-(b+c)^2+(b-c)^2=0$ or to simplify notation $x^2+y^2=z^2+w^2$. Intersecting this with the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^4$ gives a flat 2-torus which decomposes the $3$-sphere into two solid tori. One solid torus consists of matrices of positive determinant and the other of matrices of negative determinant. Thus the determinant variety $ad-bc=0$ in this case is a cone on a 2-torus.

Since the torus is smooth, the intrinsic distances in the torus are bilipschitz with ambient distance in the solid torus filling it.  In fact, one can probably get away with a Lipschitz constant not much bigger than $\frac{\pi}{2}$.  Therefore whenever one has a straight path joining two points in $GL^+(2,R)$ one can always replace its portions "dipping" into the (cone over the) "negative" solid torus by arcs following the (cone over the) flat 2-torus while retaining Lipschitz control over length of the path.  This proves that the intrinsic and the ambient distances are bilipschitz in the 2-dimensional case.

A complete answer appears at http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01227

Comment: Actually I think I can prove the answer is yes for $n=2$ but I don't know about $n>2$ (I cut into 2 separate comments...).

Comment: That's interesing, I would like to see the proof. @YCor

Comment: But it's lengthy and time-consuming. The steps: 1 (for any $d$): the two distances are strongly equivalent if and only if on the 1-sphere interesected with positive determinant matrices, the usual distance and the spherical distance using paths of positive determinant matrices, are equivalent. 2) for $d=2$, on the 1-sphere the zero locus of the determinant function is not singular (for $d>2$ matrices of rank $\le d-2$ are singular points). (...)

Comment: (....) 3) (any $d$) if on the sphere the two distances (let me denote $d$ and $d^+$) are not equivalent, one can find in the 1-sphere, after extraction, converging sequences $A_n\to A$, $B_n\to B$ such that $d(A_n,B_n)/d^+(A_n,B_n)\to 0$. Note that $\det(A),\det(B)\ge 0$. If $A\neq B$ this means that $d^+(A_n,B_n)\to\infty$. Otherwise $A=B$. So in both cases, we obtain that there exists some $P$ with $\det(P)\ge 0$ at the neighborhood of which $d^+$ is not equivalent to $d$ (being unbounded in the first case, where $P=A$ or $B$, or taking $P=A=B$ in the second case). (...)

Comment: 4) If $P$ is invertible, this is obviously a contradiction. If the rank of $P$ is $d-1$, then the determinant function on the sphere has nonzero gradient at $P$ and thus locally up to a diffeomorphic change of chart, the determinant looks as a nonzero affine map vanishing at $P$, so there is no distortion at its neighborhood.  5) In particular if $d=2$, we have a contradiction, so both distances are equivalent. If $d=3$, I do not know if there is distortion at the neighbourhood of a rank 1 matrix as the determinant is singular there. But this should be doable.

Comment: @katz Thanks for the your solution. Can you please elaborate on why the smoothness of the torus implies that "intrinsic distances in the torus are bilipschitz with ambient distance in the solid torus filling it"? I am not entirely convinced by your argument. How exactly do you replace the portions dipping into the negative solid torus by arcs following the flat 2-torus while retaining Lipschitz control over length of the path?

Comment: @AsafShachar, this is just a compactness argument (but one can also get explicit estimates because the Clifford torus in the 3-sphere is so well understood).  Namely, on the torus you have two distances: the intrinsic one and the extrinsic one.  Since the torus is compact, these distances are necessarily equivalent, i.e., bilipschitz.

Comment: ...here the smoothness of the torus guarantees that the ratio of the distances tends to $1$ as the points collide. In general the determinant variety will have singularities and the metrics will not be bilipschitz. @AsafShachar

Comment: @AsafShachar, is the email for you provided at the HUJI website correct?

Comment: @katz I agree with the compactness argument showing that if there are no singularities then the metrics are bilipschitz (works for any polynomial on the sphere, not only determinant); I sketched the argument before you modified your answer. But I don't understand your claim of the converse "the metrics will not be bilipschitz" in case of a singularity; it fails for arbitrary polynomials and I don't know in the particular case of the determinant around a rank 1 matrix in $3\times 3$ matrices.

Comment: @katz: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: ​Actually, I do not understand why it's enough to show equivalence on the intersection with the unit sphere. If we consider two matrices $A,B$ with different norms (​i.e they belong to two different spheres), then what can we say on their distances based only on the fact we know the distances on each sphere are equivalent?